# Jitsi behind ALB connection to websocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-application-load-balancer, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am struggling with Jitsi behind AWS ALB.

I have configured load balancer, opened TCP: 443, 80, 4443, UDP: 10000.

Created target group etc. frontend works but the video doesn't start:

[image: You've been disconnected]

Error in the console is:

`WebSocket connection to wss://jitsi.<censored>.org/xmpp-websocket?room=test' failed:  _connect @ strophe.umd.js:5463`

I will really appreciate the advice.

UPD: I can disable websocket by adding these variables to .env

```
ENABLE_SCTP=1
ENABLE_COLIBRI_WEBSOCKET=0
ENABLE_XMPP_WEBSOCKET=0
```

But this isn't secure and therefore the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ALB does support websockets. But you can't configure the setup like this. One thing you can do is switch over to NLB, but this would require some reconfiguring of the security groups, Listeners, target groups, etc.
Why don't you want to use WebRTC?

UPDATE

Come to think of it, Amazon ALB Listeners offers HTTP and HTTPS and WebSockets initially contact the app with HTTP (ws) or HTTPS (wss)

So the ALB shouldn't care about the stream switch/upgrade.
The only thing is that the websocket is designed to stay open, and the ALB kills a connection after x seconds (60s i think). But Jitsi doesn't go Idle, so maybe this isn't a problem.
I'll try it out and get back to you :)

UPDATE
It took a while, but it works.
You need to set a couple of things:

```
JVB_TCP_HARVESTER_DISABLED=true
JVB_TCP_PORT=4443
JVB_TCP_MAPPED_PORT=4443
```

Set the following back to the default values (leave blank)

```
ENABLE_SCTP
ENABLE_COLIBRI_WEBSOCKET
ENABLE_XMPP_WEBSOCKET
```

Make sure you set the PUBLIC_URL variable for all containers (except Prosody)
This should be it. Got it working here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can ask a question to the author as a comment instead of posting it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can be added a part of answer as comment.

Comment: A comment is not possible as a new user with a rep of 1 ;)